# How to throw an exception on data mismatch

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and am learning how to handle exceptions. I want the program to throw an exception if I try to add two variables of different types. When I compile, I get the mismatch error and the message that + won't work with the two types, but I want it to throw the exception instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    try{
       int var1 = 6;
       string var2 = "7";
       if (typeid(var1).name() == typeid(var2).name()){
          cout << var1 + var2;
       } else {
          throw 99;
       }
    }catch (int e){
       cout << "caught a " << e << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The meta lesson here is that you don't need dynamic exception handling to catch a static programming error.

Comment: “When I compile, I get the mismatch error … but I want it to throw the exception instead” – **why**? That makes no sense whatsoever. It’s a *good* thing that this is a compile error rather than a run-time exception.

Comment: Not to mention that `typeid(var1).name() == typeid(var2).name()` doesn't really mean anything, since it compares pointers (which may be different even if the text they point to is the same.

Comment: I agree that this is a good thing and understand what you guys are saying. This is a scaled down version of an assignment. I am adding to a class (Car) that has overloaded operators. I could say cout << ford+chevy and it would add my two speeds together. For the latest assignment, we had to "templatize" the class so we could instantiate  the speed with int, float, or string. We are then to add an int instance to a string instance. The second part of the assignment is to add exception handling, so I'm wanting to block mismatched types from being added. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks James. I didn't know that. My thought was to try and compare type somehow before allowing addition.

Comment: @user2709365 Not really.  You'd better post some code which shows what you are really trying to do, because it's far from clear.  Different instantiations of different templates are totally unrelated classes, so the problem doesn't change; any attempt to add them would be a compile time error.

Comment: @user2709365 To compare them, just compare them.  `std::type_info` supports `==` and `!=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but for
anything like what you describe in your comment to work, you
need inheritance.  All of your template classes must derive from
a common base, where the comparison takes place:

```
private:
    virtual void doBinaryFunction( Base const& other ) const = 0;
public:
    void binaryFunction( Base const& other ) const
    {
        if ( typeid( *this ) != typeid( other ) ) {
            throw std::runtime_error( "Type mismatch" );
        }
        doBinaryFunction( other );
    }
```

In each of the derived classes, you `static_cast` the `Base
const&` to `Derived const&`, and then do whatever has to be
done.

If you want to handle mixed types, you'll need some form of
double dispatch.

You also mention implementing "addition", where the types to be
added are different.  The problem here is that addition has
a return type which depends on the types being added.  The usual
way of handling this is by deciding on a canonical type (say
double).  In this case, the best solution is probably to provide
some sort of virtual function which returns the value as the
canonical type, do the addition with the canonical type, and
return it.

Never the less, this smacks of very bad design.  First, of
course, you don't "add" `ford` and `chevy` and expect to get the
sum of their speeds.  That just doesn't make sense.  You might
add `ford.speed()` and `chevy.speed()` (although I don't think
that adding the speed of two unrelated cars makes sense either),
but then regardless of the implementations, the `speed` function
has to return the canonical type for speed; *if* `ford` and
`chevy` have different concrete types, you will be calling
through the interface defined in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.
But if you really want, you can:

```
std::string& operator+(std::string& lhs, int rhs)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("That's really stupid.");
    return lhs;
}
```

Comment: No, my example is a scaled down version of the actual program. lhs could be int, float, or string. Same for rhs. I just used those as potential input types.

Comment: Then you just have to write operators overload for all those types :) If you want to do useless stuff, you can write a bit more it won't change anything ^.^ And actually you can try with templates ;)